# Bootstrap modal form doesn't show data

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I am developing an ASP.NET webforms app, and I have a minor problem.
The page contains a GridView control that displays a list of office records, and the user can either add a new record or edit an existing one.
Either way, a Bootstrap modal form is launched.  When the user clicks the 'Edit' button in the GridView, it loads the full record using the DataKey value of the selected row, and that SHOULD populate the fields of the modal form, which is then displayed.

The thing is, all of this works, except when the form opens, the fields are blank.  The record does load from the database, and no error occurs, either in the ASP.NET code or in the javascript console in debug mode.  Am I missing something about how this should work?

The modal code is as follows:

```
            <div class="modal fade" id="mdlOffice" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add/Edit Office Record</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="tbOfficeName" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">Office Name:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9 d-flex">
                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="flex-fill form-control input-md rounded w-100" ID="tbOfficeName" runat="server"
                                        MaxLength="32" ClientIDMode="static" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="tbOfficeMgr" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">Office Manager:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9 d-flex">
                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="flex-fill form-control input-md rounded w-100" ID="tbOfficeMgr" runat="server"
                                        MaxLength="32" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="tbAddress1" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">Street Address:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9 d-flex">
                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="flex-fill form-control input-md rounded w-100" ID="tbAddress1" runat="server"
                                        MaxLength="32" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="col-md-9 d-flex">
                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="flex-fill form-control input-md rounded w-100" ID="tbAddress2" runat="server"
                                        MaxLength="32" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="tbCity" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">City:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control input-md rounded w-100" ID="tbCity" runat="server"
                                        MaxLength="32" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                </div>
                                <label for="tbZIP" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">ZIP Code:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
                                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control input-md rounded w-100" ID="tbZIP" runat="server"
                                        MaxLength="32" ClientIDMode="static" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="tbPhone" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">Telephone:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-9 d-flex">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbPhone" CssClass="form-control input-md rounded w-50" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="tbLocalRate" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">Local Rate:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
                                    <input type="number" id="tbLocalRate" placeholder="0.5" step="0.05" min="0" max="1" runat="server"
                                        class="form-control input-md rounded w-50" />
                                </div>
                                <label for="tbGlobalRate" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">Global Rate:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
                                    <input type="number" id="tbGlobalRate" placeholder="0.5" step="0.05" min="0" max="1" runat="server"
                                        class="form-control input-md rounded w-50" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="tbLocalRateCap" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">Rate Cap:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbLocalRateCap" ClientIDMode="Static" pattern="^\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$"
                                        value="" data-type="currency" placeholder="$50.00" runat="server"
                                        CssClass="form-control input-md rounded w-50" />
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="tbID" runat="server" />
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Save Changes" OnClick="BtnSave_Click" />
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel/Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the code in the ASP.NET code-behind file to load the selected record from the GridView into the modal is as follows:

```
        protected void GvOffices_RowCommand ( object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e ) {
            int dataKeyValue = (int)gvOffices.DataKeys[int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())].Value;
            var ofc=OfficeDB.Get(dataKeyValue, out bool ok, out string err);
            
            tbAddress1.Text = ofc.Address1;
            tbAddress2.Text = ofc.Address2;
            tbCity.Text = ofc.City;
            tbGlobalRate.Value = ofc.GlobalRate.ToString ( );
            tbLocalRate.Value = ofc.LocalRate.ToString ( );
            tbLocalRateCap.Text = string.Format ( "${0}", ofc.LocalRateCap );
            tbOfficeMgr.Text = ofc.OfficeMgr;
            tbOfficeName.Text = ofc.OfficeName;
            tbPhone.Text = ofc.OfficePhone;
            tbZIP.Text = ofc.ZIPCode;
            tbID.Value = ofc.ID.ToString ( );
            
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript ( this, this.GetType ( ), "Pry", "openModal()", true );

        }
```

Again, all of this code works without throwing an error of any kind, and a record DOES get loaded from the database via a custom object:

```
    var ofc=OfficeDB.Get(dataKeyValue, out bool ok, out string err);
```

Still, I don't understand why the form fields aren't being populated.  Help please?

Comment: I do not see, `@model ` nor do I see `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.something)`

Comment: This is an ASP.NET WebForms app, not MVC or Razor

Comment: The problem here is many. For one, you can't pop a model form, and THEN HAVE ANY postback occur. (browser page travels up to server - code behind runs, and then WHOLE page is re-sent back down to the client to be re-plotted. Any post back will BLOW OUT the dialog you just launched. While the dialog form is displayed then again ANY post back during that dialog form blows out the dialog. jQuery.ui dialogs are MUCH cleaner, much more flexible and they work 100x better then bootstrap dialogs. I STONG recommend using jquery.ui (but same post back rules do apply to jquery.ui idialogs).

Comment: I think just navigating to a new page (using a server.redirect in place of response.rediect will work much better for editing the details (and the reason is then you can continue to use standard buttons and post back events - if you use a BS dialog form then no postbacks or server logic can be used (unless you use ajax calls). Given my comments? I'll take a look at what  you posted - see if I can cook up a solution, but you fighting a losing battle unless you want to write lots of JavaScipt and use ajax commands inside of that dialog form.

Comment: You have to pop the dialog form AFTER the code behind runs - not before!!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out the answer is to wrap the modal code in an UpdatePanel control, like so:

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="mdlOffice" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add/Edit Office Record</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="tbOfficeName" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">Office Name:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9 d-flex">
                                            <asp:TextBox CssClass="flex-fill form-control input-md rounded w-100" ID="tbOfficeName" runat="server"
                                                MaxLength="32" ClientIDMode="static" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="tbOfficeMgr" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">Office Manager:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9 d-flex">
                                            <asp:TextBox CssClass="flex-fill form-control input-md rounded w-100" ID="tbOfficeMgr" runat="server"
                                                MaxLength="32" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="tbAddress1" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">Street Address:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9 d-flex">
                                            <asp:TextBox CssClass="flex-fill form-control input-md rounded w-100" ID="tbAddress1" runat="server"
                                                MaxLength="32" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <div class="col-md-3">&nbsp;</div>
                                        <div class="col-md-9 d-flex">
                                            <asp:TextBox CssClass="flex-fill form-control input-md rounded w-100" ID="tbAddress2" runat="server"
                                                MaxLength="32" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="tbCity" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">City:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
                                            <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control input-md rounded w-100" ID="tbCity" runat="server"
                                                MaxLength="32" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                        </div>
                                        <label for="tbZIP" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">ZIP Code:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
                                            <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control input-md rounded w-100" ID="tbZIP" runat="server"
                                                MaxLength="32" ClientIDMode="static" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="tbPhone" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">Telephone:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9 d-flex">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbPhone" CssClass="form-control input-md rounded w-50" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="tbLocalRate" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">Local Rate:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
                                            <input type="number" id="tbLocalRate" placeholder="0.5" step="0.05" min="0" max="1" runat="server"
                                                class="form-control input-md rounded w-50" />
                                        </div>
                                        <label for="tbGlobalRate" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">Global Rate:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
                                            <input type="number" id="tbGlobalRate" placeholder="0.5" step="0.05" min="0" max="1" runat="server"
                                                class="form-control input-md rounded w-50" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label for="tbLocalRateCap" class="col-md-3 text-right col-form-label">Rate Cap:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-3 d-flex">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbLocalRateCap" ClientIDMode="Static" pattern="^\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$"
                                                value="" data-type="currency" placeholder="$50.00" runat="server"
                                                CssClass="form-control input-md rounded w-50" />
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" id="tbID" runat="server" />
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Save Changes" OnClick="BtnSave_Click" />
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel/Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then, in the code-behind, add this line of code to the RowCommand event of the GridView control just before calling the script code to display the modal:

```
    updModal.Update ( );
```

This allows me to populate the fields of the form from the code-behind and display them on the click of the GridView.

Thanks for the feedback I did get from some of you guys.  Have a great day!